# Font coming out as Times New Roman in Older Browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts

Older browsers don't seem to compute the following CSS:

```
 .text {
    font: normal 10px Arial;
 }
```

When I look at the page in older browsers, the text comes out as Times New Roman.

What is the best way to declare a font family and size so that it is recognized by the widest possible audience?

Comment: http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html

Comment: How "old" are we talking? The font property is supported in all browsers: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font/

Comment: The obvious explanation would be that the user’s system lacks a font called Arial. But this would not depend on the age of the browser. You need to provide more information, such as specific browsers (name, version, platform) where the issue appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I'm obviously not an expert myself, but what I generally do is the `font-family:` attribute which you can declare s many fonts as you want (Ie `Font-family: Arial, 'Times New Roman', sans-serif;` ) So that the browser can go through the list one by one to see if it can run it. If not it'll go the the next item on the list. As far as fonts that run on the majority of browsers is obviously not the same, which is the main reason why you put several fonts for a backup. However you can also import other font styles from the web for your site. [Google fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts#) , for example, provides a wide range of styles you can easily use. Google font's also provide you with the `link` code to import it to your code. Regarding older browsers I don't know if the feature works as well as newer versions (since I haven't had the issue myself). But the two styles that are default no matter what, that I know of, is `sans-serif` and `serif`. As for the size for text I use the `font-size:` attribute. This feature can use percentages (text 2x the size of normal is at 200%) and can even use value sizes too (15px , 2em, etc) It expands more on it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp)

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Declaring `Font-family: Arial, 'Times New Roman', sans-serif;` does not increase the odds of making the browser use Arial – it rather causes Times New Roman to be used when Arial is not available. Since this is an accepted answer, it remains a mystery what was really the question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I thought it was that they wanted Arial but didn't want Times New Roman to default at all. I mentioned Font-family mainly because it goes through each font one by one to see what is compliant as said in my answer above (knowing it doesn't increase the 'odds'). That way he/she could put any font they wouldn't mind possibly using as a backup. (I put in the Google Font thing too since I didn't know if that since it was directly from the web it would work on older browsers) But the example I used was just so that the user could see the format and interchange/add any font they want